# What is the difference between a timer and a scheduled timer in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, timer

So I was making a timer, and I came across two different statements that I didn't know the difference between. Here is my code:

```
Mover = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(MoveDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

What is the difference between that and:

```
Mover = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(MoveDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I suggestion you to read Apples documents about [run loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) to better understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled timers are automatically added to the run loop, unscheduled timers are not.
The timer functionality is the same.